# Valores por defecto en un programa de Java

Tags: java, switch

Estoy intentando hacer un juego que me saque un numero aleatorio. A este juego le he incorporado previamente un menú para seleccionar las opciones 1. Configurar, 2. Jugar, 3. Salir. Previamente cuando inicias el programa y le das a configurar tu mismo incorporas el número de intentos que quieres. Hasta ahí, mas o menos, bien. El caso es cuando la persona elija directamente la opción 2. Jugar. Obligatoriamente tienen que salir los valores por defecto de numero de intentos (numIntentos = 5) y el numero máximo (numMax = 10). Cuando ejecuto el programa utilizando directamente la opcion 2 me pone 0 intentos.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numIntentos = 0;
    int numMax = 100 ;
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {

        System.out.println("1. Configurar");
        System.out.println("2. Jugar");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");

        try {

            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion 1");
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Seleccione el numero de intentos permitidos");
                    numIntentos = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Seleccione el numero maximo");
                    numMax = scan.nextInt();
                   
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion 2");
                    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int numOculto = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1); //numero aleatorio del 0 al 100
                    int b;//numero que el usuario introduce
                    int i;
                    int pruebas = 0;
                    System.out.print("Tienes "+numIntentos+" intentos. Escribe un número entre 1 y 100: ");
                    b = teclado.nextInt();
                    
                    for (i = 0; i <= numIntentos; i++) {
                        if (numOculto == b) {

                            System.out.println("¡Has ganado! Has necesitado " +pruebas+ " intentos");
                            break;

                        } else if (i == numIntentos) {
                            System.out.println("Has perdido! El número es el: " + numOculto+ " Numeros de intentos consumidos "+pruebas);
                            break;

                        }else if (numOculto > b){
                            System.out.println("El numero secreto es mayor que " + b);

                        }else if (numOculto < b){
                            System.out.println("El numero secreto es menor que " + b);
                        }if (i <= 1) {
                        System.out.print("Otro intento: ");
                        b = teclado.nextInt();

                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        int x = (int) (numOculto / 10);
                        System.out.println("Una pista, la primera cifra es " + x);
                        System.out.print("Inténtalo de nuevo: ");
                        b = teclado.nextInt();

                    } else if (i >= 10) {
                        System.out.print("Te queda un intento... ");
                        b = teclado.nextInt();
                    }
                        pruebas++;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 3");
            }
        }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
            sc.next();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Dices que el numero de intentos por defecto debería ser 5, y el valor máximo de los números por defecto debería ser 10, pero los tienes inicializados a 0 y 100 respectivamente. Si entras por la opción 2 sin configurar esos valores, estarán con el valor que hayas inicializado las variables. Fíjate además que luego cuando calculas el número oculto tienes metido el número 100 a machete en lugar de tener la variable numMax, por lo que siempre te va a calcular números hasta el 100 aunque cambies la configuración.

Comment: @ordago Por dios... esa tontería de nada era? Y yo dandole vueltas y vueltas y nada... Jolín muchas gracias. Tengo que estar más atenta que sino... xDD MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Revisa un par de cosas más: la variable pruebas va ir valiendo lo mismo que la variable i (la inicializas a 0 e incrementas a cada iteración) por lo que puedes omitirla y utilizar i+1 para indicar el número de intentos si el usuario acierta el número secreto. La otra cosa es el bucle for, que estás haciendo con <= Si por ejemplo pones 3 intentos el bucle se ejecutará 4 veces (0, 1, 2, 3)